# TensorFlow vid2depth icp_op load fails: dynamic module and init function

Tags: python, tensorflow

Info formatted like requested on bug reports, but I figure I'll ask here first.

#### System information

- **What is the top-level directory of the model you are using**:
  research/vid2depth
- **Have I written custom code (as opposed to using a stock example script provided in TensorFlow)**:
  Build system fixes only
- **OS Platform and Distribution (e.g., Linux Ubuntu 16.04)**:
  Ubuntu 16.04, Python 2.7 or Python 3.5
- **TensorFlow installed from (source or binary)**:
  pip
- **TensorFlow version (use command below)**:
  ('v1.6.0-0-gd2e24b6039', '1.6.0')
- **Bazel version (if compiling from source)**:
  Installed from package manager, 0.15.2
- **CUDA/cuDNN version**:
  CUDA 9.0, cuDNN 7.1.2.21-1+cuda9.0
- **GPU model and memory**:
  GTX 1080
- **Exact command to reproduce**:
  After compiling icp_op.so, run the command: 
  python train.py \
  --data_dir ~/vid2depth/data/kitti_raw_eigen \
  --seq_length 3 \
  --reconstr_weight 0.85 \
  --smooth_weight 0.05 \
  --ssim_weight 0.15 \
  --icp_weight 0 \
  --checkpoint_dir ~/vid2depth/checkpoints

#### Describe the problem

Describe the problem clearly here. Be sure to convey here why it's a bug in TensorFlow or a feature request.

There seems to be a bug in either the model.py script or the icp_op.so library compiled within vid2depth. I'm not a python expert so I'm looking for help on tracking down the issue.

The command listed above is from the vid2depth wiki page, and results in the following error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "train.py", line 41, in 
    import model
  File "/home/user/tensorflow_models/models/research/vid2depth/model.py", line 25, in 
    from ops.icp_op import icp
ImportError: dynamic module does not define init function (initicp_op)

On python3, similar error but different init function name (PyInit_icp_op, I think).

Answer (score 0):

It's may happens because icp_op_kernel.cc build with incorrect flags.
U can get archive [there](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/issues/5168#issuecomment-439813177) (build for Ubuntu 18.04). If not help, try to compile with flags, getting by following commands in u're python environment:

`python -c 'import tensorflow as tf; print(tf.sysconfig.get_compile_flags())'
python -c 'import tensorflow as tf; print(tf.sysconfig.get_link_flags())'`

Also looks like name of op doesn't match in c++ and python code. So i just rename `icp_op.so` to `Icp_op.so` and rename it in python file. After thap all tests are passed.